# how to find slope of this polar curve: $r^2=\sin(2\theta)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polar-coordinates

Given $r^2=\sin(2\theta),\;$ how to find the slope of the tangent line at $x=0$ ?

If the question were $r=\sin(2\theta)$, it would be o.k.

but since it is $r^2=\sin(2\theta)$, I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: Recall that $x = r\cos \theta$, so at $x=0$, you need $r\cos \theta = 0 \iff\cos \theta = 0$ (or else $r = 0.)\;\;$ ...unless you meant to write $\theta = 0$ instead of $x = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I plugged in theta = 0 for which x=0, slope is calculated to be 1. When i looked up the graph

Comment: the slope at x=0 looked to be 0, not 1. Could you check ?

Comment: I didn't say $\cos(0) = 1$, I specified we need to know when $\cos \theta = 0$, and $\cos \theta = 0 \implies \theta = \pi/2 \pm \pi$.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{ dy}{dx} = \frac{d (r \sin \theta)}{d ( r \cos \theta) } = \frac{ \sin \theta dr + r \cos \theta d \theta }{ \cos \theta dr - r \sin \theta d \theta} = \frac{ \sin\theta (dr/d\theta) + r \cos \theta }{ \cos \theta (dr /d \theta) - r \sin \theta}$$

Then use:

$$r^2 = \sin ( 2 \theta) \iff r = \pm \sqrt{ \sin (2 \theta)} $$

Comment: Well-done, Jeb! (+1)